# using part of RAM as local storage

Tags: optimization, storage, virtuoso

I'm setting up a virtuoso server on my local machine, the databse is not big (about 2GB)

The application I'm using the server for needs to make a very large number of queries and the results need to come fast.

The HDD I'm using is mechanical, so it's not that fast, I am now trying to find a way to allocate part of my main memory as a local storage so that I can put the database file on it.

is there's an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a software called RamDisk plus

you can see a demo here: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAdRsQJBEBE

This software allows you to create a disk partition right out of your RAM

Answer (score 0):

That's not what RAM is for.

If your server ever lost power, you would lose all of the data.

If you want a faster HDD, get one with a higher RPM, or get an SSD.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the server is only used for queries, no updates in database, so it doesn't matter when the server restarts that  I have to move the .db file in the RAM-Created partition

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [performance Tuning Guide](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning)...

It details, how to configure exactly what you are looking for.

Data is still held on disk - but the more data that can be loaded into memory too will see better performance.

get *all* your data into memory and that's probably as fast as it gets :-)